# Implement little software into toolTip

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I created an tooltip using qTip 2, where an image and the title is displayed.

But:

If you click the image inside the tooltip, a modal box displays.
In this modal-box the image should be displayed, but it isn't.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8378/

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <img src='{{{img}}}' alt='image could not be displayed' class='profilep' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you take a look at the source code of the modalbox?
Am I not allowed to use `{{{img}}}` inside it?

Comment: Don't cheat the code-with-JSFiddle rule. Copy your code into your question so that others can help you more easily

Comment: done, so can you refer to the problem?

Comment: It looks like you're using a templating engine (with `{{{img}}}`). Is the image showing a "broken image" icon? If so, check the path that is generated with your developer tools to make sure it exists

Comment: what makes you think qTip will open a modal box? I can't find anything here that indicates it does: http://qtip2.com/api

Comment: no broken image, just the alt-tag appears, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/fDavN/8378/